# Issue in execution of python code to create s3 bucket

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services

I hav installed `aws cli`
using gitbash.

I am able to run cli commands

I want to run a python code to create a s3 bucket.

Do I need to install anything more? I can see python in aws --version itself.

I want to run python code in gitbash.

kindly help begineer to python

Comment: The awscli itself is written in Python which is why you see the Python version string. It's just there for information and problem diagnosis. If you want to program AWS using a Python SDK, then you need Python (obviously) and the boto3 package. You don't need the awscli but it won't hurt, and it's very useful so I would keep it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `aws cli` to run `aws` python sdk.

You need to install the [python sdk](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-python/), which is called `boto3`.

To install it run

```
pip install boto3
```